# Whitelist IP by detection IP from browser

Tags: ip-address, verification, phone-call, whitelist

I have setup phone verification system for my site. Client will access link and they will get a call by entering number on that link. Now I want to whitelist client IP which will grant him access on all areas.

How can I whitelist client IP by detecting IP from browser and then add IP to server firewall. (I am using Linux server with caopa)

Answer (score 0):

That's a terrible approach to security. Many mobile network providers use a relatively small number of public IP addresses and NAT to provide internet access to their customers. Others internally cache data (T-Mobile Germany does that), yet others enforce the use of proxies.

IP-based authentication has never been safe, and you should never rely on it. Any form of cookie-based session is safer and to be preferred. If your application is not HTTP-based, and thus cannot make use of cookies, you will need to implement user sessions based on secrets or even better cryptography yourself.